# Isolated marker won't be displayed when filters are applied to be the single one amongst nearby clusters

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, markers, angular

I have markers all around the world, thousands of them. In some areas more close to each others, in other areas some even have a number of countries between them.

Let's take the SINGLE marker in Turkey. The next closest cluster (min 2 markers) is in Moldova.

In the frontend, I have created filters for the countries. When the user selects only Turkey, the marker is not displayed, it's like it doesn't exist.

BUT, when the user selects Turkey and Moldova (can be other countries with clusters (NOT SINGLE ONES) nearby!) Turkey's marker is displayed.

OR, IN AN OPPOSITE MANNER, if I select United States of America AND Turkey, Turkey isn't displayed, but the USA markers are displayed.

The same happens for other countries with only 1 marker.

Another example:
Trinidad and Tobago and Ecuador. Each country has a single marker. Filtered individually, no marker is displayed as there aren't clusters close by. Filtered together, their markers are displayed.

This makes me believe that these 'solo' markers belong to some nearby clusters and if those nearby clusters are not activated, they won't be displayed either.

I need these individual markers to be displayed when the respective country's filter is selected.

This is all the code I can share.

```
 markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
 applyButtonMethod()
  {
    //the get request works as it should.
    this.powerPlantService.getFilteredPowerPlants(this.countryNamesChecked, this.primaryFuelTypesChecked, this.otherFuel1TypesChecked).subscribe(
      response =>
      {
        this.markers.clearLayers();

    //this.markers.addLayer(L.geoJSON(response, {onEachFeature: myOnEachFeatureMethod})).addTo(this.map);
    L.geoJSON(response, {onEachFeature: myOnEachFeatureMethod}).addTo(this.map)

    function myOnEachFeatureMethod(feature:any, layer:L.GeoJSON)
    {
   //code in here just formats a pop-up above the marker, nothing that impacts the marker.
     }
```

What makes me believe the issue lies in the markerCluster group is the difference between the lines below. When I run the first line (currently commented) with the clustergroup I encounter the problem.

When I run the second line, without markerCluster, filtering same way as before, the marker/s is/are displayed(albeit with some code errors which are to be expected).

```
//this.markers.addLayer(L.geoJSON(response, {onEachFeature: myOnEachFeatureMethod})).addTo(this.map);
        L.geoJSON(response, {onEachFeature: myOnEachFeatureMethod}).addTo(this.map)
```

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @TomazicM - I have added a SS.

Comment: A picture of code doesn't meet the code requirement. The actual reproducible code snippet is needed. Screen shots showing the graphical problem will likely help.

Comment: Code should be added as text, not as image. Also I doubt that above code is enough to decipher the app behavior.

Comment: @TomazicM I have added the requested modifications.

Comment: @Vince -please see edited.